# How can I order an arrayList by the order in my enum

Tags: kotlin, sorting, arraylist, enums

I have an enum of colors in a specific order.  How can I sort my `arrayList` of colors to match the order of declaration in my enum?

```
enum class ColorsEnum(val rawValue: String) {
    red("Red"),
    orange("Orange"),
    yellow("Yellow"),
    green("Green"),
    blue("Blue")

}



fun orderByEnum(): String {

    val selectedColors  = arrayListOf("Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue", "Green")

    //sort selectedColors by the order in the enum

    return selectedColors.joinToString(", ")
    //should return "Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue"

}
```

Comment: `selectedColors` is a list with one element. Did you mean arrayListOf("Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue", "Green")?

Comment: Sorry yes, I did mean that.  I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant `arrayListOf("Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue", "Green")`

```
selectedColors.sortBy { colorName ->
    ColorsEnum.values()
        .find { it.rawValue == colorName }
        ?.let(ColorsEnum.values()::indexOf)
}
```

Explanation:

- `sortBy` extension function sorts elements in the list in-place according to natural sort order of the value returned by specified selector function.
- Then we find which enum has this specific `rawValue` using `find { it.rawValue == colorName }`.
- Finally we return the index of this enum in the declaration order using `ColorsEnum.values()::indexOf`.

Comment: For small lists this is perfectly fine, but for large lists this would become slow at some point by the repeated call of _find_.

Comment: @lukas.j Definitely, but I wanted to keep it as simple as possible and more instructional than efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
enum class ColorsEnum(val rawValue: String) {
  Red("Red"),
  Orange("Orange"),
  Yellow("Yellow"),
  Green("Green"),
  Blue("Blue")
}

val input = listOf("Red", "Yellow", "Orange", "Blue", "Green")

val sortOrderMap = ColorsEnum.values().associateBy { it.rawValue }
val result = input.sortedBy { sortOrderMap[it] }.joinToString(", ")

println(result)   // Output: Red, Orange, Yellow, Green, Blue
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be very easily achieved by just using the `sortBy` function.

```
selectedColors.sortBy { ColorsEnum.valueOf(it.toLowerCase()) }
```

It is recommended to use uppercase naming for the enum names.

```
enum class ColorsEnum(val rawValue: String) {
    RED("Red"),
    ORANGE("Orange"),
    // etc
}
```

Then you should also update the `sortBy` with:

```
selectedColors.sortBy { ColorsEnum.valueOf(it.toUpperCase()) }
```

Comment: `selectedColor`  has one element.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion for another approach, generating a lookup table (like in [lukas.j's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75777959/13598222)) as a property on the enum. It trades off memory use for speed (and possibly fewer allocations) which may or may not be useful!

```
enum class ColorsEnum(val rawValue: String) {
    red("Red"),
    orange("Orange"),
    yellow("Yellow"),
    green("Green"),
    blue("Blue"); // note the ; since we're adding more to the enum body
    
    companion object {
        // a simple, automatically generated lookup
        val ordering = values().associate { it.rawValue to it.ordinal }
    }
}



fun orderByEnum(): String {
    // some missing, one unknown
    val selectedColors  = listOf("Red", "Yellow", "Purp", "Blue", "Green")

    //sort selectedColors by the order in the enum
    val sortedColors = selectedColors.sortedBy { colorName ->
        // You can decide how to handle colours not in the lookup/enum,
        // here we're just putting them at the end.
        // This is why 'ordering' maps to numbers instead of the enum constants
        // themselves, so we can easily provide a default value - just one approach!
        ColorsEnum.ordering[colorName] ?: Int.MAX_VALUE
    }

    return sortedColors.joinToString(", ")
}
```

You're basically just deriving the lookup from the enum itself, so there's nothing to maintain, and adding properties and functions like this can make it easier to work with the enum - it is a class in its own right after all!

You could even create a function that encapsulates all this logic, and allows the enum to sort a provided list itself, sanitise case, handle invalid items, etc. But if you purely want to use it as a data structure, creating derived properties like a lookup map can make accessing that data cleaner, instead of having to wrangle the enum (and all its wrinkles) externally - no need to handle potential exceptions thrown by `valueOf` for example.

---

Also I'll mention that you might not need to do this at all - if this is all being handled internally, you should be using the enum constants themselves, not strings. In which case, you'd have a list of `ColorsEnum` which you could just call `sort()` on, you'd get their natural ordering and every item would be valid.

If you're getting this data externally, then you might want to just deserialise it to your internal enum representation (using a serialisation library) during the import/fetch, and handle invalid data at that stage as usual. That way, once you get your list, it's a collection of `ColorsEnum` again, and you handle it the same way, whether it originated internally or externally!